# Bootstrap color classes, icons, and dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have been trying to use bootstrap classes like bg-body-tertiary, or bg-secondary-subtle, as well as the dropdown functions and the icons. When I try to test code from the manual it doesn't appear the same as in the website. For example...

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary-subtle">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

shows as:

[image: navbar]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I tried verifying that I did have the version 5 installed and that the JavaScript and popper files were also correctly implemented in the code. It didn't change the display.

Comment: Those classes were [introduced in 5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color/#colors). You'll notice that they aren't even in [the docs for 5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/background/). Be sure you're following [the correct docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/background/#background-color). Why are you loading two different library file versions, one of which is a [very old beta](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2021/03/23/bootstrap-5-beta-3/), though? Time to upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS

It seems you put your css style on top of bootstrap style

Comment: You're right that it's best to load a custom stylesheet after Bootstrap, but that's not the problem here.